# Reading from Settings.settings file After Obfuscation

Tags: c#, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I've recently obfuscated a DLL using Dotfuscator CE with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. Here is the Dotfuscator.xml file I used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE dotfuscator SYSTEM "http://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/dtd/dotfuscator_v2.3.dtd">
<dotfuscator version="2.3">
  <propertylist>
    <property name="SourceDirectory" value="This Path Will Be Replaced By Visual Studio" />
    <property name="SourceFile" value="This Filename Will Be Replaced By Visual Studio" />
  </propertylist>
  <input>
    <asmlist>
      <inputassembly>
        <option>library</option>
        <file dir="${SourceDirectory}\" name="${SourceFile}" />
      </inputassembly>
    </asmlist>
  </input>
  <output>
    <file dir="${SourceDirectory}\" />
  </output>
</dotfuscator>
```

Now the problem is, the obfuscated assembly contains some information stored in Settings.settings. file, when my code tries to access data from settings file it fails with this following exception.

> The settings property 'ProxyTestURL' was not found

Here is the syntax to read setting:

```
 Dim strURI As String = My.Settings.ProxyTestURL
```

I know there is a similar question "Dotfuscator : Error after obfuscation" but it doesn't seems to be either complete or robust, though I put my comments there too but here I would expect a second opinion and more robust solution instead of renaming my settings file literals to obfuscated names(as mentioned there).

Comment: For anybody looking, the other question he mentions is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215726/dotfuscator-error-after-obfuscation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should exclude `My.Settings` from renaming. Instructions for doing so are in [the docs](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/5.27/gui_renaming.html#pctoc-exclusions-tab).

Comment: Note that I believe the GUI will apply this exclusion automatically; you might have much better results by starting with the GUI, rather than trying to hand-edit a config file.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan for response. I've used GUI and manually added MySettings file in exclusion list; and problem resolved. However, I'm still using CLI in post build command. Otherwise as soon as my DLL is built by Visual Studio, GUI opens up against all 35 DLLs one after another (even though /q parameter is passed to it), and I've to press build button in GUI again. To avoid this extra step I'm using CLI in post build event.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense - sorry for the confusion. In general, it's simplest to think of the GUI as a config-file generator, and the CLI as the actual obfuscator. They can each actually do either job, but it feels most-natural to work with them that way.